# Weird results of date conversion (DATENAME,DATEPART) using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I use this query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT DATEPART(dw,CAST('02-08-2018' AS date)) AS day
```

I'll have result 5 when 02-08-2018 is Thursday.

What is even weirder in DATENAME week starts from 0, so 0 is Monday and if I use something like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
    SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEPART(dw,CAST('02-08-2018' AS date))) AS day
```

I will get Saturday, but if I'm just using DATENAME just on casted date:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
    SELECT DATENAME(dw,CAST('02-08-2018' AS date)) AS day
```

I will get Thursday- correct result.

My question is: What is happening especially in the first query that is giving me back 5? And if DATENAME(dw,...) starts from 0, is DATEPART(dw,...) starting from 0 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing weird there. With date set to DMY your '02-08-2018' would mean August 2nd, 2018 which is Thursday. Also, weekdays start from Sunday, thus it gives 5 for the weekday.

In your second query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEPART(dw,CAST('02-08-2018' AS date))) AS day
```

you are not checking date name for August 2nd, 2018 but for 5 which is casted implicitly to a date and is a saturday. IOW you are sort of doing:

```
SELECT datename(dw,DATEADD(d,5,CAST('00010101' AS DATE)))
```

Odd and undocumented maybe but it is how SQL server is behaving.

When you cast to a date you get the Thursday as expected.

Anyway, SQL server also have problems in converting strings to a date\datetime based on language and settings, it is more reliable not to depend on language and settings and specify the date as 'yyyyMMdd'. ie:

```
SELECT DATEPART(dw,CAST('20180802' AS date)) AS day
```

EDIT: BTW datename(dw, ...) has nothing like start from 0 or 1. It just returns the day of week name.

Comment: Btw: "5" (`=DATEADD(day, 5, 0) = DATEADD(day, 5, '01-01-1900')`) is "06-01-1900". :-)

Comment: @WolfgangK, why did you add 5 to '19000101' I don't understand. Are you trying date math? You might create another question.

Comment: No, I just wanted to say that "5", interpreted as a date, is 5 days after the "date 0", which is '19000101' in SQL Server (a Monday).

Comment: Oh I see. I always thought it was 00010101 based but you are right it is using 19000101 instead. Thanks.

Comment: By "it starts from 0" I meant that 0 day is Monday.

Comment: @kubaklamca, indirectly yes. 19000101 is day 0 and it is a monday.